# Accessing an object's instance variable from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, object, instance-variables

Teaching myself Ruby so please bear with me. If I create an object with several defining attributes and push this object into an array how do I access one of those attributes in another method to use it in a control flow scheme? I'm making a banking ATM program for fun. My code is below...

```
class Bank


    class AccountMaker
        attr_accessor :account_number, :name, :balance, :pin

        def initialize(account_number, name, balance, pin)
            @account_number = account_number
            @name = name
            @balance = balance
            @pin = pin
        end
    end

    def initialize
        @accounts = []
    end

    def add_account(account_number, name, balance, pin)
        account = AccountMaker.new(account_number, name, balance, pin)
        @accounts << account
    end

    def login_screen(accounts)

        def account_number_login(accounts)
            puts "Please enter your 7 digit account number."
            account_number_input = gets.chomp 
            puts accounts.instance_variable_get(:account_number)

            if (/^\d{7}$/ === account_number_input) and (account_number_input === (what should go here) )
                thank_you_msg()
                pin_login(account_number_input)
            else 
                error_msg()
                account_number_login()
            end
        end
```

I have more code after this but its not pertinent to the question. Essentially I want to extract from the accounts array :account_number and use it in the if statement within the Login_screen function to see if the account actually exists. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accounts` is an array. So you have to access one of its elements' `account_number` instance variable. For example the first element's:

```
# accounts[0] would return an instance of `AccountMaker `
accounts[0].instance_variable_get(:account_number)
```

Also, you don't need to use `instance_variable_get`, since you already declared it as accessor. So, you can just call `account_number` method on it.

```
accounts[0].account_number
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Now what if I wanted to match it up against objects? Say I have several different objects with diff it account numbers and I wanted the one object account that matched with what account number the user inputs?

Comment: You would probably want to use [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) instead. The account number would be a key and the actual account the value.

Comment: I thinking that as well. I went ahead made it a hash, so same question as before only how do I access the Hash within the array, specifically the :account_number value?

Comment: No, I meant throw away your array and use hash instead. `@accounts[account_number] = AccountMaker.new(account_number, name, balance, pin)`. When you want to check if there is an account with this account number: `if(@accounts[account_number_input]) ... else ...`.